# convergence of an alternating series without $a_n$

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I have an infinite series that goes like:

3-$\frac{69}{5}$+$\frac{834}{25}$-$\frac{7734}{125}$+$\frac{62109}{625}$-$\frac{455859}{3125}$+$\ldots$

I can generate more terms of this series if needed. The problem is I cannot figure out $a_n$ for this series.

I want to find out if this series converges or not. Please help me out.

Comment: In principle one cannot tell anything from the first few terms. But note that if the terms do not have limit $0$, then the series does not converge. Alternation of signs does not help.

Comment: The magnitude (discarding the sign) of each term increases as more and more terms are calculated. Does that mean that the series is diverging?

Comment: Yes, if that is the case then the series does not converge.

Answer (score 0):

Because each term is $>1$, a sequence going infinitely would be divergent, as each term is adding more, no subtraction.

An infinite sequence that has infinite addition with no/limited subtraction is divergent.